# Unexpected display of return value of point in emacs

Tags: emacs

If I go to the end of my `.emacs` file, and execute `(point)` with `M-:`, I get the following message:

```
37018 (#o110232, #x909a, ?邚)
```

Why does emacs feel the need to tell me what unicode character corresponds to the current position in the buffer?

The issue for me is that on OS X 10.9.3, emacs 24.3.92.1, `point` is *sometimes* very noticeably slow when I invoke it interactively, and I think it may be because it takes some time to look up the character, #x909a in this case. I am not sure how to debug this.

Comment: What output do you get from `C-x =` (`what-cursor-position`)?

Comment: @choroba At the end: `point=36937 of 36936 (EOB) column=0`; just before the end: `Char: C-j (10, #o12, #xa) point=36936 of 36936 (100%) column=7`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a feature :)  Emacs Lisp doesn't have a separate type for characters (though XEmacs does), so characters are represented as integers.  `(point)` returns an integer, so `eval-expression` cannot tell for sure whether you meant it as a number or as a character.

The formatting of the output is done in `eval-expression-print-format` in `simple.el`.  Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any configuration option that could be used to turn this feature off.

The best workaround I can think of is to evaluate `(format "%s" (point))` instead of just `(point)`, or using <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>=</kbd> instead.

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you for pointing me to `eval-expression-print-format`.